# QTimer and QThread odd behavior

Tags: python, pyside, qthread, qtimer

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
import sys
from time import sleep

class MyWorkerThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWorkerThread, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        timer1 = QTimer()
        timer1.singleShot(1000, self.alarm_goes1)
        print "Timer 1 Start"
        timer1.start()

    def alarm_goes1(self):
        print "goes off 1"


class MainFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.thread = MyWorkerThread(self)
        print "Thread Start"
        self.thread.start()

        timer2 = QTimer()
        timer2.singleShot(1000, self.alarm_goes2)
        print "Timer 2 Start"
        timer2.start()

    def alarm_goes2(self):
        print 'goes off 2'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainFrame()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

```
Thread Start
Timer 2 Start
Timer 1 Start
goes off 2
```

Please, explain why alarm_goes1 doesn't execute. And how can I make it do it?

---

EDIT:

```
def run(self):
    timer1 = QTimer()
    timer1.singleShot(2000, self.alarm_goes1)
    print "Timer 1 Start"
    timer1.start()
    self.exec_()
    self._alive = True
    while self._alive:
        print 'this part will not execute'
        self.sleep(1)
```

With the `self.exec_()` both timers will work fine, but the part inside while loop won't. Without the `self.exec_()`, just one of the timers work, but the while loop will work.

I want both the timers and the while loop working together.

I tried moving the `self.exec_()` inside the while loop, but it will only run once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer posts a `QTimerEvent`, but there is no event-loop running in the thread to process it.

So you need to do something like this:

```
    def run(self):
        timer1 = QTimer()
        timer1.singleShot(1000, self.alarm_goes1)
        print "Timer 1 Start"
        timer1.start()
        # start the clock
        clock = QTimer()
        clock.start(1000)
        clock.timeout.connect(self.tick)
        # start the thread's event loop
        self.exec_()

    def tick(self):
        print 'tick'
```

and it would probably be wise to add this to the `MainFrame` class:

```
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # exit the thread's event loop
        self.thread.quit()
```

Comment: Nothing after the `self.exec_()` will run. Edited the question.

Comment: @f.rodrigues. Using a `while` loop like that is not going to work: it will just block the GUI. All you need is a simple timer to tick off the seconds (see my updated answer). And in fact, if you're trying to implement an alarm clock, you should seriously consider getting rid of the thread, and just do *everything* with timers.

Comment: Damn you are right. I forgot that timers could be reusable.